# How to click on list item by using RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, remotewebdriver

I have this hierarchy:
And I want to click on item in List view, I doing it by this, but it doesnt work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//FrameLayout/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/ListView[4]")).click();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@class='android.widget.TextView' and @name='Settings']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:(if the list elements has same id/name)

```
List<WebElement> allItems = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")); 
allItems.get(1).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this    , it should work

```
WebElement wlobj = driver.findElement(By.name("Settings"));
wlobj.click();
```

otherwise try

```
driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@name='Settings' and @index='0']");
```

text and content-desc can be used in (By.name)